# How come mousdown doesn't work on <html>-tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The mousedown-event only works if I click an elemnt, not the html-element. Why and What can I do about it?

```
var curFocus;
$(document.body).delegate('*','mousedown', function(){
    if ((this != curFocus) && // don't bother if this was the previous active element                
        ($(curFocus).is('.field'))  // if it was a .field that was blurred
    ) {
        $('.' + $(curFocus).attr("id")).removeClass("visible"); // take action based on the blurred element
    }

    curFocus = this; // log the newly focussed element for the next event
});
```

Comment: probably create an element the size of the html tag and work with it?

Comment: Don't you mean `'#' + $(curFocus).attr("id")` - or better, `'#' + curFocus.id`?

Comment: Why do `.delegate('*','mousedow...`? That is the same as just placing a `mousedown` on the body, except that you have to run a selector for each `mousedown`. I'd just do `$(document.body).mousedown(function(e){...`. Then instead of `this`, use `e.target`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<html>` tag is a bit to general, it includes non-visible elements like the `<head>`, try using the `<body>` tag.

Comment: what tag? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Kristoffer, @Orbling hadn't escaped his in-line code properly, so they were stripped/rendered invisible. @Orbling, please take a read of the [SO Mark-down help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/).

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were binding to the html element, I didn't see your code previously - did you add it?  I would assume the delegate() filter only applies to it's children and not the body itself.  Try making the function bound to the mousedown event on body separately as well as the delegate.  Or perhaps perform the delegate on document itself, rather than document.body.

Comment: Take your anonymous function out of the delegate() call and bind it to a variable.  Then use the variable in it's place on the delegate() call, and follow it immediately with a .mousedown() binding as well.  Or change "document.body" to "document" in the initial jQuery brackets $(document).

Comment: @Orbling, no worries; I only pointed out the markdown help page in case you hadn't seen it (I wasn't trying to be a jerk about it [=) )](http://xkcd.com/541/).

Comment: @David Thomas, quite alright, I had not seen it previously, well worth a look. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The `<body>` element is inside the `<html>` element, not the other way around. And your code will only respond to mouse-down events coming from *children* of the body element, not even the `<body>` element itself. See http://jsfiddle.net/5T8tW/ for a demo.

To make the code respond to such events, change `$(document.body)` to `$(document)`. If you don't want to respond to events coming from the `<html>` element but only its children, you could use `$(document.documentElement)`, which is the `<html>` element. Note that as the event bubbles up through the DOM tree, your event handler may be fired more than once; use `return false;` at the end to prevent that.

Comment: great demo! What can I do about it?

Comment: @Kristoffer Nolgren: It's in my answer now.